# I have Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, html, syntax

I am building a custom search engine that allows searching by several fields. The error "syntax error, unexpected end of file" appears and it tells me it is on line 201 of my code, right in the last php (<?php } ?>).

My code:

First is the connection, followed by the POST of the fields for the search and order, I build the form and then open the queries with $query for any filled fields, and the options to order the results found. The table is "jefe", and its data is "cedula_jefe" with 'search'; "boss_name" with 'searchname'; "boss_lastname" with 'lastnamesearch'; "boss_sex" with 'searchsex'; "boss_date" with 'searchdatefrom' and 'searchdateto'. All followed after the first query with an "else" to then show the data found that matches.

```
<?php  include ('../../bd.php')?>

<?php 

if (!isset($_POST['buscar'])){$_POST['buscar'] = '';}
if (!isset($_POST['buscarnombre'])){$_POST['buscarnombre'] = '';}
if (!isset($_POST['buscarapellido'])){$_POST['buscarapellido'] = '';}
if (!isset($_POST['buscarsexo'])){$_POST['buscarsexo'] = '';}
if (!isset($_POST['buscarfechadesde'])){$_POST['buscarfechadesde'] = '';}
if (!isset($_POST['buscarfechahasta'])){$_POST['buscarfechahasta'] = '';}
if (!isset($_POST['orden'])){$_POST["orden"] = '';}


?>


<a href="../jefe/index.php">Volver a Jefe</a>


        <center><h4>Buscador:</h4></center>

<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Cédula a Buscar</label>
            <input type="text" name="buscar" value="<?php echo $_POST["buscar"] ?>">
            <label>Nombre a Buscar</label>
            <input type="text" name="buscarnombre" value="<?php echo $_POST["buscarnombre"] ?>">
            <label>Apellido a Buscar</label>
            <input type="text" name="buscarapellido" value="<?php echo $_POST["buscarapellido"] ?>">
        </div>

        <h4>Filtrador Buscador</h4>

        <div>
                <table>
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                        <th>
                                                Sexo a Buscar
                                                <select id="buscarsexo" name="buscarsexo">
                                                    <?php if ($_POST["buscarsexo"] != '') { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $_POST["buscarsexo"]; ?>"><?php echo $_POST["buscarsexo"]; ?></option>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                    <option value="">Cualquiera</option>
                                                    <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                                                    <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
                                                </select>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Buscar Nacimiento Desde:
                                            <input type="date" id="buscarfechadesde" name="buscarfechadesde" value="<?php echo $_POST["buscarfechadesde"]; ?>" >
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Buscar Nacimiento Hasta:
                                            <input type="date" id="buscarfechahasta" name="buscarfechahasta" value="<?php echo $_POST["buscarfechahasta"]; ?>" >
                                        </th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                </table>
        </div>


        <div>
                <table>
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                        <th>
                                                Selecciona el Orden
                                                <select id="orden" name="orden">
                                                    <?php if ($_POST["orden"] != '') { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $_POST["orden"]; ?>">
                                                    <?php
                                                    if ($_POST["orden"] == '1'){echo 'Ordenar por Cédula';}
                                                    if ($_POST["orden"] == '2'){echo 'Ordenar por Nombre';}
                                                    if ($_POST["orden"] == '3'){echo 'Ordenar por Apellido';}
                                                    if ($_POST["orden"] == '4'){echo 'Ordenar por Sexo';}
                                                    if ($_POST["orden"] == '5'){echo 'Ordenar por Fecha más Reciente';}
                                                    if ($_POST["orden"] == '6'){echo 'Ordenar por Fecha más Antigua';}
                                                    ?>
                                                    </option>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                    <option value=""></option>
                                                    <option value="1">Ordenar por Cédula</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Ordenar por Nombre</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Ordenar por Apellido</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Ordenar por Sexo</option>
                                                    <option value="5">Ordenar por Fecha más Reciente</option>
                                                    <option value="6">Ordenar por Fecha más Antigua</option>
                                                </select>
                                        </th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                </table>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Ver">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <?php 
    if ($_POST["buscar"] == ''){$_POST["buscar"] = ' ';}
    $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST["buscar"]);

    if ($_POST["buscar"] == '' AND $_POST["buscarnombre"] == '' AND $_POST["buscarapellido"] == '' AND $_POST["buscarsexo"] == '' 
        AND $_POST["buscarfechadesde"] == '' AND $_POST["buscarfechahasta"] == '') {
            $query ="SELECT * FROM jefe ";
    }else{ 
        $query ="SELECT * FROM jefe ";

            if ($_POST["buscar"] != '' ){
                    $query .= "WHERE (cedula_jefe LIKE LOWER('%".$aKeyword[0]."%')) ";

            for ($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) { 
                if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
                    $query .= " OR cedula_jefe '%" . $aKeyword[$i] . "%'";
                }
            }

        }

            if ($_POST["buscarnombre"] != '' ){
                $query .= " AND nombre_jefe LIKE '".$_POST['buscarnombre']."' ";
            }

            if ($_POST["buscarapellido"] != '' ){
                $query .= " AND apellido_jefe LIKE '".$_POST['buscarapellido']."' ";
            }

            if ($_POST["buscarsexo"] != '' ){
                $query .= " AND sexo_jefe = '".$_POST['buscarsexo']."' ";
            }

            if ($_POST["buscarfechadesde"] != '' ){
                $query .= " AND fecha_jefe BETWEEN '".$_POST['buscarfechadesde']."' AND '".$_POST["buscarfechahasta"]."' ";
            }

    if ($_POST["orden"] == '1' ){
            $query .= " ORDER BY cedula_jefe ASC";
        }


        if ($_POST["orden"] == '2' ){
                $query .= " ORDER BY nombre_jefe ASC";
            }

        if ($_POST["orden"] == '3' ){
                $query .= " ORDER BY apellido_jefe ASC";
            }

        if ($_POST["orden"] == '4' ){
                $query .= " ORDER BY sexo_jefe ASC";
            }


        if ($_POST["orden"] == '5' ){
                $query .= " ORDER BY fecha_jefe ASC";
            }


        if ($_POST["orden"] == '6' ){
                $query .= " ORDER BY fecha_jefe DESC";
            } ?>

        <?php }

        $sql = $conexion->query($query);

        $numeroSql = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    ?>

    <p><?php echo $numeroSql; ?> Resultados Encontrados</p>

</form>

<fieldset>
<div>
        <table>
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th>Cédula</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Apellido</th>
                                <th>Sexo</th>
                                <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php While($rowSql = $sql->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <?php { ?>
                                <th><?php echo $rowSql["cedula_jefe"]; ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $rowSql["nombre_jefe"]; ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $rowSql["apellido_jefe"]; ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $rowSql["sexo_jefe"]; ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $rowSql["fecha_jefe"]; ?></th>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

I've already checked and the truth is... I do not understand why...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the code you posted. Maybe the problem is in `bd.php`.

Comment: That error generally means you have unbalanced brackets -- more open brackets than matching close brackets.

Comment: Barmar:

What the bd.php includes is just (<?php


$conexion = mysqli_connect(
'localhost',
'root',
'',
'consejo_c',
);
 ?>)

I have checked the brackets and the truth is I can't find any of them open...

Comment: Do you get that error if you remove the `include` line?

Comment: in the code you just posted for the bd.php file there's an extra comma (,) at the end of the parameter list.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but your usage of interior brackets with the `while` loop are really confusing

Comment: Your code has lots of "sections". Try deleting one of these sections and see if you still get the error. If you don't, the problem is in that section. If you do, try deleting more. Repeat.

Comment: I removed the (include bd.php) and still the error persists. I also removed the (,) in bd.php.

Comment: I know that the error is in the query, the (cedula_jefe) only searches for quantities even if it is a (text), the others (nombre-apellido jefe) are text

Comment: @Begincode you are now asking about a problem in the query, you should focus on one problem per question. Have you solved the "unexpected end of file" error.

Comment: The error still persists, after having tried almost all of these solutions, I have already touched the code in basically all its functions and I still do not understand where the problem could be. I still see that "syntax error: unexpected end of file".

Comment: Isn't the `<center>` tag deprecated by CSS? Shouldn't there be a `LIKE` in the SQL generated for additional keywords? Have you checked the relative priority of `OR` and `AND` operations in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is more of a comment but I'm posting it as an answer so I can include a screen shot.

I put your code on a local web server but I cannot reproduce the "unexpected end of file" error.

[image: screen shot of rendered page]

Which makes me think it's a data issue. Are you displaying any data which contains characters that could be interpreted as HTML or PHP code?